# Drop records from dataframe based on the null present for any column

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, null, drop

How to select only the rows with IDs for which there are no rows which contain nulls.

```
  +---------+------+-----+
  |AccountID|  Name|Price|
  +---------+------+-----+
  |       11|miguel| null|
  |       11|luisa |   21|
  |       12|  hary|   90|
  |       13|  null|   99|
  |       14|  marg|   90|
  |       14|  null|   99|
  +---------+------+-----+

  DF.na.drop().show()

  +---------+------+-----+
  |AccountID|  Name|Price|
  +---------+------+-----+
  |       11|luisa |   21|
  |       12|  hary|   90|
  |       14|  marg|   90|
  +---------+------+-----+
```

na.drop() removed all rows that have null values on any column of DataFrame. I would want to know how can I drop other record having AccountID 11.
Delete all the records for same AccountID if null was present in any column/records for that particular AccountID

In this case output should be only AccountID 12.

As 11 and 14 AccountID's were having null values.

```
  +---------+------+-----+
  |AccountID|  Name|Price|
  +---------+------+-----+
  |       12|  hary|   90|
  +---------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase your question, you want to select only the rows with IDs for which there are no rows which contain nulls.

```
// select rows which have a null
val idsWithNulls = DF.filter(col("Name").isNull || col("Price").isNull)
// based on those ids remove 'bad' ids
DF.join(idsWithNulls, Seq("AccountId"), "left_anti")
```

The result will be:

```
+---------+----+-----+
|AccountId|Name|Price|
+---------+----+-----+
|       12|hary|   90|
+---------+----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to provide the list of columns as Array(Columns) in filter condition? My dataframe is not consistent and so the column names. How can I use map here?

Answer (score 1):

Try with **`df.na.drop()`**

**Example:**

```
df.show()
//+---+----+----+
//| id|name|dept|
//+---+----+----+
//|  1|   a|null|
//|  2|null|   a|
//|  4|   d|   c|
//+---+----+----+

df.na.drop().show()
//+---+----+----+
//| id|name|dept|
//+---+----+----+
//|  4|   d|   c|
//+---+----+----+
```

---

**df.na.drop()** accepts

- `all`(drop if all column values are nulls).
- `any`(drop any column value is null) params.

---

```
df.na.drop("any").show()
//+---+----+----+
//| id|name|dept|
//+---+----+----+
//|  4|   d|   c|
//+---+----+----+

df.na.drop("all").show()
//+---+----+----+
//| id|name|dept|
//+---+----+----+
//|  1|   a|null|
//|  2|null|   a|
//|  4|   d|   c|
//+---+----+----+
```